# Angular formgroup setvalue duplicates the values in other controls

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have defined a FormGroup inside a FormArray. I am setting a value in a specific FormControl. But when I set the value using `setValue` method in a specific control, that value is duplicated in other controls in the same formGroup.

```
this.listItemForm = this.formbuilder.array([]);
let fromGroup_ = formbuilder.group({
  '8c159f74-b4208eae_image1_page1_1': [''],
  '8c159f74-b4208eae_image2_page1_1': ['']
});
this.listItemForm.push(fromGroup_);

let formGroup:FormGroup = listItemForm.at(0) as FormGroup;
if(formGroup.get('8c159f74-b4208eae_image1_page1_1')){
  formGroup.get('8c159f74-b4208eae_image1_page1_1').setValue('new value added');
}
console.log(formGroup.value);
```

**OUTPUT**

**Expected**

```
{
  8c159f74-b4208eae_image1_page1_1: 'new value added', 
  8c159f74-b4208eae_image2_page1_1: ''
}
```

**Actual output**

```
 {
  8c159f74-b4208eae_image1_page1_1: 'new value added', 
  8c159f74-b4208eae_image2_page1_1: 'new value added'
}
```

I am using Angular version 7. Not sure why it is duplicating. Any thoughts?

Also please note, I have this above formArray inside a formgroup. This  is added just to explain the question. I know this works when I tried the above alone.

**UPDATE**

Those form controls were added dynamically. Therefore somehow all the formcontrols have same reference. Therefore the issue. I have found out.

Thanks for who all tried help!

Comment: Try replacing `setValue` to `patchValue`.

Comment: Tried, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `FormGroup` has properties of type `[key: string]: AbstractControl`.

```js
let fromGroup_ = new FormGroup({
  '8c159f74-b4208eae_image1_page1_1': new FormControl(''),
  '8c159f74-b4208eae_image2_page1_1': new FormControl(''),
});
```

I'm not sure why tsc even lets you compile that code to be honest, maybe the type definition differs in Angular 7?

Comment: I used form builder, updated the code above. This is how I used in my project. It was a typo.

Comment: This is same. one is the functional way and the other is object-oriented way.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

Use `FormControl` while defining values for `FormGroup`

```
this.listItemForm = new FormArray([]);
let fromGroup_: any = new FormGroup({
  '8c159f74-b4208eae_image1_page1_1': new FormControl(''),
  '8c159f74-b4208eae_image2_page1_1': new FormControl(''),
});
this.listItemForm.push(fromGroup_);

let formGroup: FormGroup = this.listItemForm.at(0) as FormGroup;
if (formGroup.get('8c159f74-b4208eae_image1_page1_1')) {
  formGroup
    .get('8c159f74-b4208eae_image1_page1_1')
    .setValue('new value added');
}
console.log(formGroup.value);
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-reactive-form-validation-xmswmj

Comment: I used form builder, updated the code above. This is how I used in my project. It was a typo. This is same. one is functional way and other is object oriented way.